# How to improve Java generics wildcard signature

Tags: java, generics, containers, wildcard

I'm trying to create DI container `get` method, but struggling with signature. Currently I have this definition:

```java
public Object get(Class<?> key) {
  // returns instance of `?`
}
```

The part of my code which I dont like much is usage of the `get` method:

```java
IRouter router = (IRouter) container.get(IRouter.class);
```

where I have to cast return with `(IRouter)`. Any ideas how to change method signature to make usage like this?

```java
IRouter router = container.get(IRouter.class);
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a scoped method parameterized type :

```
public <T> T get(Class<T> key) {
  // ...
  return (T) foo;
}
```

Here I suppose that `foo` is not typed as `T`.
If it is already typed as `T` you can of course return it without cast.

You could so invoke it :

```
IRouter router = container.get(IRouter.class);
```

Comment: You are welcome :) I advise you to download source code from Spring core classes. It should help you for your requirement.

Comment: Yeah, sure :) but I am just playing with Java as PHP developer and trying to verify my concepts of OOP as fast as much free time I can allocate to myself :D